# i tried to compare 2 string in python but it fails

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I wnt to compare a string in a iist and variable but the output is awlays false

ive used is and == then I thought because elemen in my list is not string then I try to chnage it in to a str using str() func but it doesnt work

```
        obj='ana'
        # haha[22][0] is 'ana'
        obj1=str(haha[22][0])
        if obj is obj1:
            print('true')
        else:
            print('false')

        print(obj1)
```

first I tried to change == into is but it doesnt work then I though I need to change elemen in my list into str() it doenst work too

I would like to compare it thank you so much for the answer

Comment: In `print('true)` you open a quote and don't close it again.

Comment: i edited but still dont work

Comment: I think string use " " instead of ' ' . ' ' is for characters

Comment: " and ' can both be used for strings. And `obj == obj1` will return True if the strings are equal. Your problem may be in the strings themselves not being equal.

Comment: element in my list is ('ana',1) 1 is how much ana appear in my txt , i tried to use == but it dont work

Comment: @Matriac that is for C++ and C#. In python you can use both ' and "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is almost certainly something to do with what's stored in your list. Also in general == is for comparing value and 'is' is for comparing identity so you should use == in this situation.

What is output by the last print?

'ana' == 'ana' will always return true so without specifying where the element is set there isn't enough information to work out what your issue is.

If it prints 'ana' it may be worth printing the hash function of each object to compare.

I'd like to have written this as a comment but I don't have enough rep to comment :/

Comment: outuput of last print is ana not 'ana' and my element in my list is ('ana',1) 1 is how much ana appear in my txt

Comment: What is printed at the end?

Comment: sorry i forgot that haha[22][0] is not ana hhehe im sorry thank you so much